# php getcwd() resolving target of symlink instead of current directory

Tags: php, apache, symlink, resolve, getcwd

As far as I am aware, php's `getcwd()` (and similar functions eg `dirname(__FILE__)`) are supposed to return the current directory of the file being executed.

If the current directory happens to be a symlink to another directory, php (presumably in conjunction with apache) is supposed to return the path showing the symlink name as the 'directory' you're in.

Example:

```
from /var/www,
directory 'one' contains index.php
symlink 'two' points at directory 'one'

one/index.php: <?php echo getcwd(); ?>
```

Accessing http://localhost/two/index.php in a browser shows `/var/www/one`.

I would expect it to show `/var/www/two`

Does anyone know if this is a php or apache setting I can change? Or am I unable to use symlinks in this manner?

Comment: Did you figure it out?  I'm interested in this same use case.

Comment: Is Apache configured to follow symLinks? Like `Options FollowSymLinks`

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with Apache.  It's a PHP "feature".  If you enter this at the command line `mkdir a; ln -s a b; php -r 'chdir( "b" ); echo getcwd();'`, php will show you that you're in a directory called 'a', even though you chdir()ed to 'b'.

Answer (score 12):

OK figured it out.  Use `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` if over the browser.  Over the command line, you can get the current symlinked directory using `exec("pwd")`

Comment: For just directory, without file name: dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);